# install 'Line" in ubuntu 14.04 64 bit using wine

Tags: command-line, wine, 64-bit

im using ubuntu 14.04 with the 64-bit version.

i have a problem when i tried to install "LINE" using wine.

in the article i have read, it says that i have to download a package file, so i download it. then, i have to extract the package into one folder called "Line"

i already have installed wine, and the articles says that i have to put the folder in the wine folder ".wine", and put it in program files.

my problem is, in 64 bit version, there are 2 types of program files folder, the x64 and x86. where can i put the line folder ?

the next problem is, it says i have to edit the file in /usr/bin/line , so i use the terminal and open it with gedit. but when it opened, it says that i have to run it with "administrator user". and when i tried to open it manually (not using terminal), it says the same, that it need a administrator access to open the file.

im sorry for my bad english :D hope mine answered assap :D

Comment: I googled and found [this](http://www.tanmoybiswas.com/post/93017922616/install-line-messenger-in-ubuntu-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Use `file` utility on the executable file, it will show you if your app is 32bit (x86) or 64bit. 

`file /storage/TE_CC430EV_433/EW430-5514-Autorun.exe
/storage/TE_CC430EV_433/EW430-5514-Autorun.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows`

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me (Ubuntu 14.04 64)~

1. Install Wine

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wine
   ```
2. Install VC++ 2008 Runtime

   ```
   winetricks vcrun2008
   ```
3. Run Line (Download LineInst.exe from [LINE](http://line.me/en/download), the one in PC Windows. )

   ```
   wine LineInst.exe
   ```